# Как правильно оценить временные затраты на работы по оптимизации SQL Server

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, производительность

Суть проблемы такова:

Есть заказчик, у заказчика есть БД (SQL Server), которая по его мнению работает не так быстро, как хотелось бы. Поэтому он хочет ускорить ее, т.е. выжать из БД все, на что она способна. В связи с чем, он просит оценить временные затраты на работы по оптимизации. Но здесь возникает резонный вопрос, а как оценить их правильно!? Какие вопросы в первую очередь следует задать заказчику о его БД, на что обратить внимание и от чего в целом отталкиваться?

Comment: Отталкиваться от суммы, которую он согласен потратить. Спросить, на каком накопителе СУБД сейчас работает: если на HDD, то перенести на SSD, да и вообще железо модернизировать - это может оказаться гораздо дешевле прочих способов оптимизации (однако, боюсь, тогда вы станете не нужны и потеряете работу, поэтому предлагайте аккуратно).

Comment: Сначала надо оценить а возможно ли это. Надо узнать, что можно при этом делать с БД и запросами. А то очень часто заказчик не готов модифицировать само приложение, работающее с БД. А вся нагрузка создается запросами, которые написаны в самом приложении и модифицировать их нельзя. И никакая оптимизация БД не спасает от select * двух миллионов строк, без where, из приложения ради получения одной записи, отфильтровываемой клиентом (это еще обычный, не самый тяжелый случай)

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Действительно очень верное замечание по поводу свободы действия.

Comment: В любом случае надо начинать с обследования системы - а это уже работа, которая требует времени, и соответственно чего-то стОит... А вообще мне кажется наиболее разумным оценивать стоимость не всех работ, а стоимость единицы времени работы. Чем дольше продлятся работы, чем больше задействовано работников, тем лучше результат, но и больше расходы. И когда заказчик решит, что расходы перестали оправдываться результатом, он скорректирует направление (скажем, потребует уменьшить количество работников в группе с пропорциональным снижением расходов) или вообще "прикроет лавочку".

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто делится своим мнением, оно важно для формирования общего представления о проблематике.